# React - Material UI Menu not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm using the menu/menu item from material ui. It seems to have an issue if I try to render it based on a condition. Refer below...

```
const AddSelectItemButton = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <Fab 
            aria-controls="simple-menu" 
            aria-haspopup="true" 
            onClick={handleClick} 
            className={classes.addButton} 
            size="medium" 
            color="primary" 
            aria-label="add"
        >
            <AddIcon />
        </Fab>
        <Menu
            id="simple-menu"
            anchorEl={anchorEl}
            keepMounted
            open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
            onClose={handleClose}
        >
            <MenuItem onClick={handleDelete}>Delete Item</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem onClick={handleAddNew}>Add Item</MenuItem>
        </Menu>
        </>
    )
}
```

Inside the main container I have something like this

```
return (
    <div className='my-5'>
        <Paper className="pl-5 pr-5 pb-5 position-relative"> 
            <Typography className="pt-4 mb-4 text-center" variant="h4">My Items</Typography>
            {!isAuthMode &&
                <AddSelectItemButton />
            }
            <Grid container spacing={3} justify="center">
            {allItems.items.map(item=>
                <Grid key={item.id} item xs={5} className={`mt-4`} style={{height: '200px'}}>
                        <Card className={`${classes.root} d-flex ${classes.packInner}`}>
                            <CardActionArea className="d-flex">
                                <CardMedia
                                    className={`${classes.media} ${classes.cardImage}`}
                                    image={item.image}
                                    title={item.brand}
                                />
                                <CardContent className={classes.textContainer}>
                                    <Typography gutterBottom variant="subtitle1">
                                        {item.brand}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                        {item.name}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary">
                                        Weight: {item.weight}
                                    </Typography>
                                    <Typography variant="body2" color="textSecondary" className={classes.itemDescription}>
                                        {packInfo.description.length > 80 ?
                                            (`${packInfo.description.substring(0, 77) + '...'}`)
                                            :
                                            packInfo.description
                                        }
                                    </Typography>
                                </CardContent>
                            </CardActionArea>
                        </Card>
                </Grid>
            )}
            </Grid>
        </Paper>
    </div>
);
```

If I don't do the condition and include the code in the original rendering. The menu loads at the position of the button. With the condition, it renders far top left of the page and not at the button.

[image]

Anyone have an idea or need more info?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need conditional rendering?

Comment: @radovix I want to use the same component to hide this button when not in auth mode.

Comment: Can you please add the code of the whole component (including callbacks and other stuff)?

Answer (score 1):

```
{!isAuthMode && (
  <AddSelectItemButton />
)}
```

Comment: This was useful for helping me rewrite my conditional inline. But didn't fix my issue. I posted a picture of what it looks like.

Comment: Is there any other element in the code use that flag, isAuthMethod?

Comment: Try to wrap Typography and AddSelectItem inside a div . If you are setting the flag using  usestate hook , it is asynchronous and there is a chance of rendering that component after all other UI

Comment: <div>.                                                                       <Typography className="pt-4 mb-4 text-center" variant="h4">My Items</Typography>
            {!isAuthMode &&
                <AddSelectItemButton />
            }                                                                               </div>

Comment: @user1038449 there is no other element using this and the div trick did not work sadly :/

Comment: But the add icon is displaying correctly, right? Can you try to wrap the fab and menu inside a div with a flexDirection coloumn style

Comment: @user1038449 sadly did not help. And yes, the add icon displays correctly. You can see this in the image I posted. I can't find any resources out there.